# How to install jschr's bootstrap-modal in Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to install jschr's bootstrap-modal found here: https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal to use in my rails project.

The github page's instructions indicate to:

- Include css/bootstrap-modal.css after the main bootstrap css files.
- Include js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js and js/bootstrap-modal.js after the main bootstrap js files.

What does this mean? I thought bootstrap was installed in rails via inclusion in the gemfile and running bundle update/install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to install:

[Vicente Reig created a Ruby Gem for you to use!](https://github.com/vicentereig/bootstrap-modal-rails)

Follow his installation instructions to add the gem to your gemfile and then install the gem. This will add the files you need to your gem directory.

### How to initialize:

You need to add two `require` statements:

The first in your `application.js` file:
The first few lines will be commented out with `//`,this is where you add the `.js` call.

```
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-modalmanager
```

Do the same in your `application.css` file:

```
//= require bootstrap <--(this should already be there.)
//= require bootstrap-modal
```

If your `application.css` file doesn't have the `require bootstrap` line, then it might have this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

if so, add this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-modal";
```

That way, bootstrap-modal loads second.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Do I need to download the files to some directory? Rails is telling me it `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-modal'`

Comment: I updated my answer. This involves adding a gem to your gemfile. If this piece is unfamiliar to you, check out Bundler for an idea of how it works: http://bundler.io/

Comment: strangely enough action controller is still looking for `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-modal'
  (in /home/tanner/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:13)` despite installing and updating gems

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I had to change the gemfile and remove the `group:assets` Thanks for the find!